# Slowing C++ output on terminal

Tags: c++, ascii, ascii-art

I wrote a program that simulates the *Game of Life*. Basically the world is implemented by a bi-dimensional std::vector of `bool`. If the `bool` is true the cell is alive, if is false the cell is dead. The output of the program is the system at each time step, completely in ASCII code:

```
[ ][0][ ]
[ ][ ][0]
[0][0][0]
```

The problem is that the program runs obviously fast and each time step is printed too quickly: I can't see how the system evolves. Is there some trick to slow down the output (or directly the program)?

**EDIT**: I'm on Mac OS X 10.7. My compiler is GCC 4.7.

Comment: Put in a sleep command between successive updates to allow you to visualise the process. The sleep will depend on what OS you are using.

Comment: Eventually you may want to evolve your output to 'fat' pixels on a graphic screen.  Besides making it a good exercise for doing graphics it lets you see the evolution more visually.  Sometimes you get some that create fantastic graphics such as the machine gun life model.  Fat pixels BTW are like a 4x4 output of pixels to represent a single entity on your grid.  After fat pixels you could then try sprites which now gives you aging creatures that thrive or die then fade away.  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use standard C++ (C++11):

```
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    while (true) {
        // draw loop
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(20));
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could use a library that lets you specify an interval at which to call your draw function. OS X has Grand Central Dispatch (a.k.a. libdispatch). Using GCD you could create a dispatch timer source that calls your draw function with a specified frequency.

```
dispatch_source_t timer = dispatch_source_create(
    DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_TIMER, 0, 0, dispatch_get_main_queue());

dispatch_source_set_timer(timer, DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
    duration_cast<nanoseconds>(milliseconds(20)).count(),
    duration_cast<nanoseconds>(milliseconds( 5)).count());
// the API is defined to use nanoseconds, but I'd rather work in milliseconds
// so I use std::chrono to do the conversion above

dispatch_source_set_event_handler(timer,
    []{ your_draw_function(); });
// I'm not sure if GCC 4.7 actually supports converting C++11 lambdas to
// Apple's C blocks, or if it even supports blocks. Clang supports this.

dispatch_resume(timer);

dispatch_main();
```

[libdispatch reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html)

Comment: I like the first option with C++ standards library. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever system you are using, it will have some kind of sleep function that you can call that will suspend your program for a specified period of time. You do not specify what OS you use, so I cant give exact details, but it sounds like the approach you are looking for.

If you call sleep for a certain length of time after drawing each update of the image, your program will sleep for that time before resuming and drawing the next update. This should give you chance to actually see the changes

If you want higher resolution time sleep you can look at `nanosleep` and `usleep`

Comment: I dont use Max OS X but this link might help you http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/sleep.3.html

Comment: I used it by command line as `sleep 5` and de prompt disappeared for 5s. How I use it in my C++ program?

Comment: @R.M. I presume you have a loop somewhere and every time an iteration happens, it will redraw your output. Put in the sleep inside the loop just after your image gets redrawn

Comment: Yes, I have a loop to draw the system. But if sleep is a command line tool, how I use it in my C++ program?

Comment: The command works also as a command line (terminal)... How I add it to my program? `sleep(5)` to sleep 5s?

Comment: try adding this `sleep(1)` in your loop just after you draw the image. You may need to #include unistd.h

Answer (score 0):

1.You can use

```
int tmp; std::cin >> tmp;
```

and program will ask you before to go further.

2.You can use loop over some calculations. Like

```
double Tmp[1000000];
for( int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++ )
  Tmp[i] = i;
for( int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++ )
  Tmp[i] = sin(sin(sin(Tmp[i])));
```

3.You can check which delay-functions you have available for you. Example is "Sleep(nSeconds)" [here](http://www.programmingforums.org/post154167.html)

4.You can save and verify you system time. Like:

```
 while (time() < time_end){};
```